# Conditional rendering react to display components

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

i have to display 2 kinds of rendering one with css another without css

```
class SearchSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: null,
      pathName: "/rule-builder"
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const handlepathName = window.location.pathname;
    console.log(handlepathName);

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="search-section">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder={this.props.placeholder || "Search lists of values ..."}
            value={this.state.input}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <span className="search-icon">
            <img src={images.SEARCH_ICON} alt="icon" title="search" />
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="category-scroll">
          {this.props.render && this.props.render(this.state.input)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchSection;
```

i want to conditionally render that if page doesn't match that link i have render page with this `<div className="category-scroll">`, if its matches then without `<div className="category-scroll">` this line

Comment: Your question lacks some clarity. Can you be more specific?

Comment: is it okay now ?

Answer (score 1):

Conditional rendering contains one condition and two different UI that depend on the condition is truthy or falsy.
Let me take an example:

```
 class SearchSection extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pathName: "/rule-builder"
    };
  }

  render() {
    window.location.pathname == this.state.pathName  ? 
    return (
      <div>
        Hello
      </div>
    ) 
     :
     return (
      <div>
       good bye
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SearchSection;
```

Comment: am seeing the expression error exactly at return statement

Answer (score 0):

This the working answer

```
    <div>
    <div className="search-section">
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder || "Search lists of values ..."}
        value={this.state.input}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <span className="search-icon">
        <img src={images.SEARCH_ICON} alt="icon" title="search" />
      </span>
    </div>
    {window.location.pathname == this.state.pathName ? (
      <div>{this.props.render && this.props.render(this.state.input)}</div>
    ) : (
      <div className="category-scroll">
        {this.props.render && this.props.render(this.state.input)}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
```